# Http Server without response.end in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having some confusion regarding the `response.end`in Node js, I have the following code.

```
const http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(req, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    setInterval(() => {
        response.write(new Date() + "\n");
    }, 1000)


}).listen(8080);

console.log("Service Running at 8080 127.0.0.1")
```

Now this above code will start printing the date in the browser after 20 seconds or more, now this code doesn't have any `reponse.end`, and it's obvious because if there was any `response.end()` then the code inside the `setIntervel` would never execute.

But doing this doesn't do anything it takes forever to load the page.

```
const http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(req, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    response.write("Test");


}).listen(8080);

console.log("Service Running at 8080 127.0.0.1");
```

But if i add `response.end` in the above code it will work just fine.

So can anyone explain this weird behavior, that why using `setInterval` without `response.end` works.

Comment: What would happen if you do `response.write("Test\n")`

Comment: Nothing happens it keep requesting the page and after some time chrome gives an error, like Page is not responding.

Comment: "why using setInterval without response.end works". Are you saying that the first code is working?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928779/node-js-delayed-response - "some" browsers only show the result when the full page is retrieved (or when the buffer is full). (what should the 'Content-Length' say?)

Comment: yes the first code is working.

Answer (score 0):

What you signal as a problem is literally what should happen. The browser asks the server for data, the server starts sending data and never signals an "okay I am done" so that the browser knows the message is done.

The problem here is your idea on how to get data into the browser from the server.

1. Set up a websocket connection so you can push data from the server to the browser. That's what it's for. Or,
2. Set up a repeating call in the browser using setTimeout or setInterval or something, and just call the server every second or something, with the server responding with tiny, tiny messages that all *actually end*.